# Cannot Perform apt update on Parrot OS

Tags: linux, parrot-os

In last two days I have installed Parrot Mate and then upgraded it to latest
I will specify the introduction to my problem

The version of my OS is as follows:

```
Linux parrot 5.10.0-5parrot1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.24-5parrot1 (2021-03-20) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Initially I had installed the MATE version but afterwards I also installed the KDE desktop Environment using apt.

After this whenever I perform **sudo apt update** I get the following error.

```
Hit:1 https://repo.windscribe.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                          
Ign:2 https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot rolling InRelease       
Ign:3 https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot rolling-security InRelease
Err:4 https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot rolling Release         
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The revocation or OCSP data are old and have been superseded.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 2606:4700:3034::ac43:aec4 443]
Err:5 https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot rolling-security Release
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The revocation or OCSP data are old and have been superseded.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 2606:4700:3034::ac43:aec4 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot rolling Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot rolling-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

My /etc/apt/sources.list.d/parrot.list contains the following lines

```
# parrot repository
# this file was automatically generated by parrot-mirror-selector
deb https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/ rolling main contrib non-free
#deb-src https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/ rolling main contrib non-free
deb https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/ rolling-security main contrib non-free
#deb-src https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/ rolling-security main contrib non-free
```

Because of the error I also tried **sudo parrot-upgrade**
but again the output was same

Any help please, Thank you: :)

Answer (score 3):

```
#sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/parrot.list
```

Change your following sources list to below mentioned ones

```
## stable repository

deb [trusted=yes] http://archive.parrot.sh/parrot rolling main contrib non-free

deb [trusted=yes] http://archive.parrot.sh/parrot rolling-security main contrib non-free

deb-src [trusted=yes] http://mirror.parrot.sh/parrot rolling main contrib non-free

deb-src [trusted=yes] http://mirror.parrot.sh/parrot rolling-security main contrib non-free
```

Save the file and try again

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this error I managed to fix it by install
`sudo apt install ca-certificates`
And make sure your time and date are correct

Answer (score 1):

I used first the command

```
# sudo parrot-mirror-selector direct rolling nonfree
```

to reset the mirrors and then

```
# sudo parrot-upgrade
```

and that's it :)

Answer (score 0):

1. `sudo su`
2. `passwd`
3. `apt update && apt upgrade -o`

Works 100%

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

change the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/parrot.list` with the current one:

```
deb https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/ parrot main contrib non-free
#deb-src https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/ parrot main contrib non-free
deb https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/ rolling-security main contrib non-free
#deb-src https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/ rolling-security main contrib non-free
```

You can find the documentation here:

> https://www.parrotsec.org/docs/mirrors-list.html